# Are there any specific quality metrics for semantic web based systems?

Tags: validation, rdf, semantic-web, ontology, metrics

I know there are metrics specifically to validate ontologies, but I need something to measure the system that communicates with them. I also know ISO 9126, but I need more specific metrics, which validates, for example, how extensible or maintainable the software is to increase or change with the ontology model.

Answer (score 1):

May be some of the work done by one of my colleagues, Filip Radulovic, might be relevant here.

[Software quality model for the evaluation of semantic technologies](http://oa.upm.es/10186/)

[Extending Software Quality Models–A Sample in The Domain of Semantic Technologies](http://www.ksi.edu/seke/Proceedings/seke11/85_Filip_Radulovic.pdf)

and [his other papers](http://scholar.google.com/citations?user=Ye1p4W4AAAAJ&hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

If understand your question precisely, I think you should read these papers:

Coupling metrics for ontology-based system : http://goo.gl/mhVs2G

Semantic oriented ontology cohesion metrics for ontology-based
   systems : http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1663922

Metrics for ontologies : http://goo.gl/auhFQK

Evaluating Evaluation Metrics for Ontology-Based Applications:
   Infinite Reflection.

Metrics for evaluation of ontology-based information extraction

Semantic oriented ontology cohesion metrics for ontology-based
   systems

Comment: Hi Eilia, thanks but all papers are related to metrics for analysing the ontology structure (if they are extensible, performs fast extraction, etc).
What I need are the metrics for evaluate the application that access the ontology, like the ISO 9126 or ISO 25010, but specific for semantic web systems. I guess there is no work related to that. But, anyway, thank you very much again.

Comment: @gui_maranhao,Your topic is very narrow and specific; however, I wish these ones give you some ideas, at least: Semantic Metrics, Conceptual Metrics, and Ontology Metrics: [An Analysis of Software Quality Using IR-based Systems, Potential Applications and Collaborations] and [Ontology Classification for Semantic-Web-Based Software Engineering ]